# Magento - How to display 4 or 5 products on homepage from a single category, create a block similar to 'New' or 'Sale'

Tags: php, magento

### History

I am using a Blanco theme for just the Responsive. I've contacted the developers but not had any response from them.

The blanco theme will only load on mobile or tablet view, else it will load up the default theme 'GHD'.

### Issue

I am trying to create a block (never done one) to display 4 or 5 products on the home page which is similar to the New or Sale blocks with Navigation arrows etc but to load up I don't know - 20 products.

I want it to pull in a category i.e. 217, and hoping to create about 3-4 of these on the homepage.

### Tried

I've tried messing with the new.phtml, spcial.phtml, and trolling through hundreds of pages on Google. I can add all products from a category but it displays them as 3 per row and shows every product from category. I don't want that.

Comment: post your code in new.phtml, spcial.phtml files.

Comment: Hi, I cannot post this, as both files are really long and for some reason it doesn't show up as a 'code'. the New.phtml & Special.phtml are default Magento files - No changes have been made.

Answer (score 0):

First `create a custom block in admin` using this

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="13" template="custom/featured-product.phtml" }}
```

after that include that block in your xml file using the block_id like this

```
<block type="cms/block" name="Promo_de">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>promo_de</block_id></action>
        </block>
```

Now call the block in your phtml like this

```
$this->getChildHtml('Promo_de');
```

**Another way**

call one phtml from another phtml like this

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template)->setTemplate('templateFolder/yourtemplate.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: Hi Kingshuk, would the $this->getChildHTml('Promo_de'); be called in head or header.phtml? I cannot see the homepage.phtml. Also, which xml file should that code go? Thanks

Comment: Hi, plus cannot see "custom/featured-product.phtml" under FTP /htdocs/app/design/frontend/default/ghdnew/template

Comment: hey this is demo..use your own..anyway you will find the home page in admin->CMS->Pages